# Javascript call nodejs and display SQL result in html

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

So far I have my project done in php, which I can see on webpage sql result. I would like to do this is javascript, and I notice nodejs is what I need, so far I can run my SQL query by using:

```
$ node my_sql_query.js
```

but I don't know how to display the SQL results in html. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: The same way as with PHP. Make an HTTP request from the browser to the Node.js server. Get a response.

Comment: This is pretty broad as asked. If you want to write a site in JS there are many ways this can be done; some very similar to PHP, some not.

Comment: HI, thank you for your comment.  I was study about nodejs on w3schools. I was able to start server, and then from command line I can get json return. Still did not find a way to see results on html. I was playing with request but so far no luck :(